# Pandas: assign categorical column based on string values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, categories

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
     A         B
1    05010001  17
2    05020001  5
3    05020002  11
4    05020003  2
5    05030001  86
6    07030001  84
7    07030002  10
8    08010001  16
```

I want to add a third column, `C`, which assigns `1` to all rows which `A` value begins with `05`, `2` to all values beginning with `07` and so forth.

The result would be:

```
     A         B    C
1    05010001  17   1
2    05020001  5    1
3    05020002  11   1
4    05020003  2    1
5    05030001  86   1
6    07030001  84   2
7    07030002  10   2
8    08010001  16   3
```

**What is the most efficient way of doing this?** My actual dataframe has 3,000,000 rows.

**EDIT**

Column `A` in my actual dataframe is called `First (C)`, with a space. I am not allowed to change it. Do I have to operate some sort of manipulation on the column's header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
firstTwo = df.sort_values('A').A.str[:2]            # sort the data frame by column A and 
                                                    # take the first two digits of column A
df['C'] = (firstTwo != firstTwo.shift()).cumsum()   # create ids based on the first two 
                                                    # digits with cumsum
df
```

[image]

Comment: One thing. In my actual case, column `A` is called `First (C)`. Playing with your snippet, this gives problems when calling the `A.str[:2]` part. I take `A.str` refers to column `A`, but what if its name is different, as in my case?

Comment: You can put them in bracket like `df.sort_values('First (C)')['First (C)'].str[:2] `